# Updating "current" class in megamenu with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a menu which is stylized through jquery and CSS so the structure is like that:

```
<div id="nav_top" class="clearfix round_top">
    <ul class="clearfix round_all">
        <li class="current"><a href="index.php"><img src="images/icons/home.png"/>Home</a></li>

        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icons/users_2.png"/>Users</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="users.php">Create user</a></li>
                <li><a href="view_users.php">View users</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="has_slide">Group management</a>
                    <ul class="slideout">   
                        <li><a href="#">View groups</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Manage permissions</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another menu item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

So, as you can see, many levels could have an anchor.

The main idea is to have the TOP level with current because that's the only part you can see without hovering.

My first approach was to capture the current URL throuh `window.location.pathname` and then iterate through every `$('#nav_top a')` with a function like this one:

```
$('#nav_top a').each(function(){
if ( path.search($(this).attr('href') != -1){
   $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass('current');
   $('.current').removeClass('current');
}
});
```

I also know I could select by href but I was going to make a performance test between both methods but, anyway, the point is that this works only for one of the levels because of the `.parent()` nesting.

How could I make this extensible to all levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this out. Using the jQuery `closest()` http://api.jquery.com/closest/.

Notice that I also switched around removing and adding the class. The way you had it would just remove it from the element you just added it to.

```
$('#nav_top a').each(function(){
   if ( path.search($(this).attr('href') != -1){
      $('.current').removeClass('current');
      $(this).closest('.top-level').addClass('current');
   }
});
```

Edit:

Add a class of `top-level` to your top level `<li>`s

Comment: Ohh sorry, won't work. Updated the question. The idea is only to have as current, the top level.

Comment: Updated my answer. Might help.